# Uploading Image Using JSON is not Working

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

Can anyone help my code structure? What's wrong with it?

**HTML**

```
 <form method="post">
      <div class="col-md-4">              
        <div class="field name-box">
           <input class="btn" name="image_file" id="image_file" type="file" style="font-size:15px;width:100%;margin-bottom:2px;" required=""/>
        </div>
      </div>     
 </form>
```

**JS**

```
        var form_data = new FormData();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrlAction() + '?btn=add_product_image',
                data:  form_data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data){

                    alert("Successfully");

                },
                error: function(ts){
                }           
            });
```

**AJAX_CONTROLLER**

```
public function add_product_image(){

    if(is_array($_FILES)){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])){
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = "product_images/"."sample_img_name".".png";
            if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)){
                // echo '<script>alert("Successfully Save")</script>';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But I've been wondering why I will get a `success` response on my ajax form? even my `upload_file` doesn't work properly. Can anyone help me?

Comment: AJAX runs error handling only if your server responses with a non-200 status code, or handling on the server times out, or due to a network error. If you want to the AJAX to fail due some handling error, you've to set the response status, ex. 500, manually in PHP.

Comment: Yes sir. I have tried to put this stuff  "console.log(ts.responseText)" on my error handling but I didn't still get an error. It will respond "Successfully".

Comment: Yes, but an AJAX call fails only when a fatal error occurs on the server, or the time browser waits for the response is exceeded, or if there's a connection failure, including 404 page was not found errors. Warnings and exceptions during PHP execution won't make AJAX to fail.

Comment: Your file is not being sent to the server. See var form_data = new FormData(); Either pass the form or append the file input control to FormData()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to append data with form_data in your js file and send response

formData.append('image_file',  $('#image_file')[0].files[0];);

```
            var form_data = new FormData();
            formData.append('image_file',  $('#image_file')[0].files[0]); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrlAction() + '?btn=add_product_image',
                data:  form_data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data){

                    alert("Successfully");

                },
                error: function(){
                }           
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

pass form Element to FormData

```
let form = document.getElementById("yourFormId");
var form_data = new FormData(form);
```

Comment: What is the problem after applying it?

Comment: Nothing happens the image wasn't still uploaded. :(

Comment: share the output of  `print '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES);`